# Setting Compiler Level For gradle generated Maven pom

Tags: maven-2, gradle

I am using gradle as project dependency manager but since I like netbeans better and can't find a native integration with maven, I copy the default pom generated by gradle as the pom.xml. But How do I set the source and target level?

my build.gradle looks like

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'java'

targetCompatibility=1.6
sourceCompatibility=1.6
```

after I run

```
gradle install
```

and check the build/poms/pom-default.xml it never configures the source nor target level which is defaulted to 1.3

what I am lacking is maven compiler plugin configuration

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and haven't been able to find how to configure that specific part of the pom. I've found all the examples where they configure license, developer stuff and so on but not the plugin specif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add that section in the very same way as the examples do it for "license and developer stuff".

Comment: I have tried and it says `> No such property: _SCRIPT_CLASS_NAME_ for class: org.apache.maven.model.Model` when I try to add `build.plugins.plugin` into `project`.

Answer (score 3):

took me a while to figure it out. Like Peter said above you can just add that section. Easier said than done though, at least for me.

Fortunately, spring is using gradle so you have lots of real world examples. check git hub

```
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        customizePom(pom, project)
    }
}

def customizePom(pom, gradleProject) {
    pom.whenConfigured { generatedPom ->
        // respect 'optional' and 'provided' dependencies
        gradleProject.optionalDeps.each { dep ->
            generatedPom.dependencies.find { it.artifactId == dep.name }?.optional = true
        }
        gradleProject.providedDeps.each { dep ->
            generatedPom.dependencies.find { it.artifactId == dep.name }?.scope = 'provided'
        }

        // eliminate test-scoped dependencies (no need in maven central poms)
        generatedPom.dependencies.removeAll { dep ->
            dep.scope == 'test'
        }

        // add all items necessary for maven central publication
        generatedPom.project {
            name = gradleProject.description
            description = gradleProject.description
            organization {
                name = 'bajoneando'
            }
            build {
                plugins {
                    plugin {
                        groupId = 'org.apache.maven.plugins'
                        artifactId = 'maven-compiler-plugin'
                        configuration {
                            source = '1.6'
                            target = '1.6'
                        }
                    }
                    plugin {
                        groupId = 'org.apache.maven.plugins'
                        artifactId = 'maven-surefire-plugin'
                        configuration {
                            includes {
                                include = '**/*Tests.java'
                            }
                            excludes {
                                exclude = '**/*Abstract*.java'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                resources {
                    resource {
                        directory = 'src/main/java'
                        includes = ['**/*']
                        excludes = ['**/*.java']
                    }
                    resource {
                        directory = 'src/main/resources'
                        includes = ['**/*']
                    }
                }
                testResources {
                    testResource {
                        directory = 'src/test/java'
                        includes = ['**/*']
                        excludes = ['**/*.java']
                    }
                    testResource {
                        directory = 'src/test/resources'
                        includes = ['**/*']
                    }
                }
            }
            developers {
                developer {
                    id = 'lnramirez'
                    name = 'Luis Ramirez Monterosa'
                    email = '*****@gmail.com'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```